# Player.CurrentFrame Script Not Updating ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I haven't worked in AS3 in almost a year because I had moved on to working with Unity, but I decided to come back and work on some more stuff because I really liked it. This question is really simple, I just need a refresh:

I'm on the main timeline of Flash and I want to trace the current frame of the timeline within "player". For some reason it just shows up as 1.

```
trace(player.currentFrame);
```

After working with this I found out that it was caused by the function not being updated constantly. How do I fix this? How can I make a function that updates itself?

Comment: What does "function not being updated constantly" actually mean? If `player.currentFrame` is returning 1, that's because it's on the first frame at that point in time.

Comment: You have an update cycle in Unity, too. In flash, it works almost identically. Either use an "enter_frame" event or setInterval or Timer instance. Check the documentation for each of them.

Answer (score 1):

The object will dispatch an `Event` of type `Event.ENTER_FRAME` when the duration of a single frame went by. (this means the event is still periodically dispatched even though the timeline is not advancing)

This would allow you to periodically check the `currentFrame` property.

However, depending on what you want to achieve, there are other options to consider.
If for example you want to trigger a certain action upon reaching a certain frame, just put a label at that frame and listen for a `FrameLabelEvent`. This improves readability, given that you use descriptive label names.
It also helps maintainability, as you can freely move the label, (if you add a few frames to an animation, for example) without breaking the code.